# Entry verification?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not even sure how to title this question. I'm still quite the newbie with databases. Here's my situation.

I have an intersection table,

intersect(**foo_id**, **bar_id**)

foo(**foo_id**, *alpha_fk*)

bar(**bar_id**, *alpha_fk*)

alpha(**alpha_id**)

When I insert (foo_id, bar_id) into the intersect table, I need to be sure that foo.alpha_pk = bar.alpha_pk for the given foo_id and bar_id.

I'm not really sure the best way to go about verifying this. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I suspect that you will need a trigger to enforce this.

Comment: If i'm understanding this correctly, you need to restrict the INSERT, upon the existence (EXISTS) of the corresponding PK's? Correct, if so, then condition your INSERT statement, using the EXISTS clause. If this sounds right, try looking up how to do that, or I can write up an example for you...

Comment: I'd rather have it be enforced by the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean function that returns whether the alpha_fk's match for a given foo_id & bar_id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_intersections_fooequalsbar(foo_id integer, bar_id integer)
RETURNS boolean AS
$$
SELECT (f.alpha_fk = b.alpha_fk)
    FROM foo f 
    LEFT JOIN bar b ON b.bar_id = $2
    WHERE f.foo_id = $1 FOR UPDATE
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Then apply the function on your intersect table in a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE intersect
ADD CONSTRAINT check_intersections_fooequalsbar CHECK
(check_intersections_fooequalsbar(foo_id, bar_id))
```

Comment: Watch out for concurrency issues here. I'd be `SELECT`ing the target rows `FOR UPDATE`.